# Error 503 Backend fetch failed

Tags: wordpress, cache, back-end

Às vezes me aparece esse erro quando estou desenvolvendo alguma aplicação no wordpress, alguém sabe me dizer o motivo???

[image: imagem do erro]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O [**Varnish**](https://varnish-cache.org) é um *"acelerador"*, ele é um sistema de cache das páginas, é um [**proxy reverso**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_reverso), ou seja as requisições passam por ele e as cópias ficam armazenadas na memória.

Sobre o erro, **geralmente** ele ocorre quando excede o limite de armazenamento na memória, você pode editar o arquivo o arquivo `varnish` (ou `varnish.params`) e ajustar parâmetro `http_resp_hdr_len` para que o servidor consiga suportar maior consumo (também depende de quanto o seu servidor tem de memória disponível para o serviço, se for *Shared* é provável que seja bem limitado).

Arquivos de configuração em diferentes distros:

- CentOS 6: `/etc/sysconfig/varnish`
- CentOS 7: `/etc/varnish/varnish.params`
- Ubuntu: `/etc/default/varnish`

No entanto se você não tem acesso as configurações só entrando em contato com a hospedagem.

**Vou deixar uma coisa bem claro**, não estou defendendo as hospedagens a maioria tem problemas pequenos mesmo que muitas vezes causam transtornos, mas este problema **na maioria das vezes** é culpa é dos web-desenvolvedores e administradores de sites (no caso provavelmente você), que injetam inúmeros JavaScript, CSS, plugins e add-ons **sem necessidade** e com isto vão tornando o site cada vez mais pesados e lentos, mesmo com incríveis sistemas de cache e etc o servidor não tem como aguentar.

Então não é bem um problema de configuração, mas sim um problema de mau uso dos recursos, então você pode tentar dar uma revisada geral, analisar se tudo é necessário ou até pensar em trocar o WordPress por uma plataforma mais eficiente, fora isto não tem muito o que fazer.

Comment: ótimo esclarecimento, obrigado!