# PHP - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF)

Tags: php, wordpress, sintaxe

Estou tendo esse erro no código no arquivo functions.php linha 2883, segue embaixo:

```
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Ticket #11289, IE bug fix: always pad the error page with enough characters such that it is greater than 512 bytes, even after gzip compression abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890aabbccddeeffgghhiijjkkllmmnnooppqqrrssttuuvvwwxxyyzz11223344556677889900abacbcbdcdcededfefegfgfhghgihihjijikjkjlklkmlmlnmnmononpopoqpqprqrqsrsrtstsubcbcdcdedefefgfabcadefbghicjkldmnoepqrfstugvwxhyz1i234j567k890laabmbccnddeoeffpgghqhiirjjksklltmmnunoovppqwqrrxsstytuuzvvw0wxx1yyz2z113223434455666777889890091abc2def3ghi4jkl5mno6pqr7stu8vwx9yz11aab2bcc3dd4ee5ff6gg7hh8ii9j0jk1kl2lmm3nnoo4p5pq6qrr7ss8tt9uuvv0wwx1x2yyzz13aba4cbcb5dcdc6dedfef8egf9gfh0ghg1ihi2hji3jik4jkj5lkl6kml7mln8mnm9ono
    -->
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" <?php if ( function_exists( 'language_attributes' ) && function_exists( 'is_rtl' ) ) language_attributes(); else echo "dir='$text_direction'"; ?>>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <?php
        if ( function_exists( 'wp_no_robots' ) ) {
            wp_no_robots();
        }
        ?>
        <title><?php echo $title ?></title>
        <style type="text/css">
            html {
                background: #f1f1f1;
            }
            body {
                background: #fff;
                color: #444;
                font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen-Sans, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
                margin: 2em auto;
                padding: 1em 2em;
                max-width: 700px;
                -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.13);
                box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.13);
            }
            h1 {
                border-bottom: 1px solid #dadada;
                clear: both;
                color: #666;
                font-size: 24px;
                margin: 30px 0 0 0;
                padding: 0;
                padding-bottom: 7px;
            }
            #error-page {
                margin-top: 50px;
            }
            #error-page p {
                font-size: 14px;
                line-height: 1.5;
                margin: 25px 0 20px;
            }
            #error-page code {
                font-family: Consolas, Monaco, monospace;
            }
            ul li {
                margin-bottom: 10px;
                font-size: 14px ;
            }
            a {
                color: #0073aa;
            }
            a:hover,
            a:active {
                color: #00a0d2;
            }
            a:focus {
                color: #124964;
                -webkit-box-shadow:
                    0 0 0 1px #5b9dd9,
                    0 0 2px 1px rgba(30, 140, 190, .8);
                box-shadow:
                    0 0 0 1px #5b9dd9,
                    0 0 2px 1px rgba(30, 140, 190, .8);
                outline: none;
            }
            .button {
                background: #f7f7f7;
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
                color: #555;
                display: inline-block;
                text-decoration: none;
                font-size: 13px;
                line-height: 26px;
                height: 28px;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0 10px 1px;
                cursor: pointer;
                -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
                -webkit-appearance: none;
                border-radius: 3px;
                white-space: nowrap;
                -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
                -moz-box-sizing:    border-box;
                box-sizing:         border-box;

                -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ccc;
                box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ccc;
                vertical-align: top;
            }

            .button.button-large {
                height: 30px;
                line-height: 28px;
                padding: 0 12px 2px;
            }

            .button:hover,
            .button:focus {
                background: #fafafa;
                border-color: #999;
                color: #23282d;
            }

            .button:focus  {
                border-color: #5b9dd9;
                -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba( 0, 115, 170, .8 );
                box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba( 0, 115, 170, .8 );
                outline: none;
            }

            .button:active {
                background: #eee;
                border-color: #999;
                -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 5px -3px rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.5 );
                box-shadow: inset 0 2px 5px -3px rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.5 );
                -webkit-transform: translateY(1px);
                -ms-transform: translateY(1px);
                transform: translateY(1px);
            }

            <?php
            if ( 'rtl' == $text_direction ) {
                echo 'body { font-family: Tahoma, Arial; }';
            }
            ?>
        </style>
    </head>
    <body id="error-page">
    <?php endif; // ! did_action( 'admin_head' ) ?>
        <?php echo $message; ?>
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php
      die();
    }
```

A linha 2883 seria em die(); alguém sabe o motivo?

Comment: Remove o `<?php endif; // ! did_action( 'admin_head' ) ?>`

Comment: Opa, ainda continua o erro

Comment: O que seria a chave na última linha? Só com esse trecho de código será difícil dizer o que está errado. Tente colocar todo o código que aborde esse trecho - não o arquivo todo, só o código que for necessário.

Comment: feito, corrigi o post

Answer (score 3):

Pode ser que você tenha esquecido de iniciar o `if ():` em algum lugar pra cima ou pode ser também que o seu IF esteja assim:

```
 <? if (...): ?>
```

Ao invés de:

```
 <?php if (...): ?>
```

Isto porque o `short_open_tag` devem estar desligados no `php.ini`, não dá pra afirmar com precisão aonde é, mas é um destes dois problemas provavelmente.

Comment: Verifiquei aqui e  short_open_tag está ativado, dei uma olhada também e todos iniciam com <?php if.
esse erro aparece só quando acesso meu site sem o www, e quando acesso normal e le volta na edição anterior do site, não aparece as novas edições que fiz.

Comment: @JeanOliveira com `www` e sem `www`, pode ser um plugin ou pode ser o cache que não exibe o erro ainda na outra

Comment: Verifiquei isso ontem, pediram pra resetar o roteador, apagar cache etc, ainda continuou, fiz uns testes com várias pessoas, o erro aparece e no celular o site é acessado normalmente, sem erro algum

Comment: @JeanOliveira não é cache no navegador é cache do lado do servidor, existem diferentes tipos de cache-back-end, como por exemplo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/218806/3635 ou wpcache (plugin), mas é só teoria, com o tanto de código que você postou e com informações tão vagas não tem como eu deduzir nada, por isso me resta as teorias que lhe passei.

Comment: Entendi agora, vou dar  pesquisada aqui e tentar resolver, obrigado pela atenção xD